# How can I limit/disable TurboCache on a EX58-UD3R?

Tags: windows-7, memory

I have 16GB of RAM installed in my computer. It is DDR3 at 1333MHZ. My motherboard is a Gigabyte EX58-UD3R MAX RAM 16GB.

In Windows 7 Professional 64-bit I can only see 12GB; the remaining RAM is allocated to the NVIDIA GeForce 9800GT GPU.

How can I limit or disable TurboCache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Wikipedia [Hypermemory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HyperMemory) is an ATI technology, much akin to Nvidias [Turbocache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TurboCache).  And from what I can tell they were both limited to use on the absolute bargain cards so that they saved money on memory by using system RAM.

I would expect your 9800GT to have either 512MB or 1024MB of onboard RAM and would not expect it to be using TurboCache (or even HyperMemory) at all, it truly is for the bargain basement cards only.

It may be that one of your memory sticks is not fitted properly (I am assuming you have 4 x 4GB sticks) or for some reason is not working properly.  Are all four sticks identical?

What makes you think that this memory is being allocated to the graphics card?

Could you also try using [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) and looking at the Memory and SPD tabs

On the SPD tab you should be able to see whether all four sticks are detected, the Memory tab should tell you if it is working in full dual channel mode rather than single channel or hybrid as might be the case if one of the sticks is not working.

Comment: First of all thanks for answering, my Card is by default 1GB, and now in dxdiag window I see 12gb of ram and my Card is 4GB, that is how I know its using it.

Comment: Thanks for noticing that its called TurboCache, I have fixed it.

Comment: Yes thank you, I have used this CPU-Z and find out that my forth module was not present, I have reinsert it and now its working. Thanks @Mokubai

Comment: @TriLLi, the memory that you see allocated in DirectX is not memory that gets directly and irrevocably allocated to the graphics card but is in fact the amount of memory that the system has available to *share* with the graphics card *if needed*, it is different to TurboCache where (I believe) memory is reserved and blocked against other use.  The shared memory is still managed and used by the system and only gets allocated when the graphics card actually needs it.  I'm glad your problem is fixed now :)